# Chrome 'click on swipe' bug

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, swipe

My site have menu, wich expand on click in mobile version.

```
jQuery('nav').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('open');
});
```

On some screens menu have bigger height then screen height.
When I try scroll it down by swipe, to get menu items at the end of menu, chrome think I clicked menu and hide it :(

In other browsers on Android all is fine.

http://funkyimg.com/u2/4674/743/951554swipe_bug.jpg — here is an example what I mean.

What I need to do to fix it?

Comment: I have a similar problem. Did you find a solution?